# JS: Unsure of when to use Promise.resolve() vs returning a new Promise

Tags: javascript

I am unsure how the usage of returning a `new Promise` vs using a `Promise.resolve()` and want to make sure my understanding of these are correct.

Given these 3 functions below:

```
    function testFunc() {
          return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
             //anything asynchronous in here has now become synchronous and 
             //execution of result of the function happens after this??
              let i = 0;
              while (i < 10000) {
                 console.log(i);
                 i++;
              }
          });
    }
------
    function testFunc2() {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               //anything asynchronous in here is still asynchronous but the 
               //`resolve()` is then synchronous?? 
               let i = 0;
                while (i < 10000) {
                  if (i === 999) { resolve('I am a test func') };
                  i++;
                }
          })
    }
------

    //synchronous function 
    
    function logMe() {
         let i = 0;
         while (i < 10000) {
            console.log("INSIDE LOG ME);
            i++;
         }
    }
```

The way I understand it is that `testFunc()` immediately resolves the Promise and anything within there becomes synchronous.  So if you were to execute:

```
testFunc();
logMe();
```

`testFunc()` would fully execute *before* `logMe()` was reached and executed.

For the `testFunc2()`, if it were executed in this order:

```
   testFunc2();
   logMe();
```

I understand it as the logic inside, in this case the while loop, would still execute synchronously and delay the execution of the following function, `logMe()`, but the `resolve` would be treated asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not that easy. You would have to use `test Func.then(logMe())`. Another option would be to run both functions in an asynchronous function:

```
async function run() {
  await testFunc();
  logMe();
}
```

The `await` is pretty simple - it runs the function and waits for it to finish, then runs the next lines. `async` is just there so that `await` can work (await does not work outside of async functions).

I prefer `async`/`await`, but many more prefer `.then`. It’s just what you want to use, both are very similar.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve, you want to asynchronously execute operation inside the loop.

```js
function testFunc2() {
  const promises = []
  for(let i = 0; i<1000; i++){
       promises.push(new Promise((resolve) => {
         console.log(i);
         resolve()
       }));
     }
  return Promise.all(promises);
}

function logMe() {
  let i = 0;
  while (i < 5) {
     console.log("INSIDE LOG ME");
     i++;
  }
}

(async() => {
  await testFunc2()
  logMe();
})();
```

Comment: thanks.  I am just trying to understand what those functions do and how they effect the event loop differently